# Object offset makes whole screen super zoomed

Tags: blenderkit

It's my first day on blender and I made stack of thin cuboids. Then added an empty(sphere) to rotate it. But on using object offset whole screen is becoming super zoomed. And when I zoom back I see dark space and an infinite long cube. Plz help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kindly attach some screenshots of what you mean. What object offset? What did you do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

The dark space you see is because of the clip start and end in your viewport (press `N` and go to view, decrease the clip start and increase the clip end) and about the infinitely long tube, just decrease the count on your array modifier.